# Retrieve Facebook reviews likes via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve some reviews data from Graph API, including comments, sub-comments, etc.

I can get `like_count` on comments using the endpoint with these parameters:

```
{page-id}/ratings?fields=open_graph_story{comments{like_count}}
```

Or the same thing with sub-comments:

```
{page-id}/ratings?fields=open_graph_story{comments{comments{like_count}}}
```

But I can't seem to find how to get them for the review itself.
I tried this:

```
{page-id}/ratings?fields=open_graph_story,like_count
```

And this (which throws an error):

```
{page-id}/ratings?fields=open_graph_story{like_count}
```

Just to be clear: in this question I separated the calls for likes on comments/sub-comments, but in reality, I'm getting all the data in a single call like this:

```
{page-id}/ratings?access_token={access-token}&fields=open_graph_story{comments{created_time,from,message,comments{created_time,from,message,like_count,user_likes},like_count,user_likes}},rating,review_text,created_time,reviewer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
`graph.facebook.com/open_graph_story_id?fields=likes`

should return a payload structured similar to below

```
{
"likes": {
"data": [
],
"can_like": true,
"count": 0,
"user_likes": false
 },
  "id": "open_graph_story_id"
}
```

Comment: This is so inconsistent with the way they expose likes on comments... Anyway, thanks.

Comment: No worries, the open graph posts boggle at the best of times!